# My data is not populating in dimple chart for dual axis. I want to show dual axis in dimple

Tags: javascript, dimple.js

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 990, 400);    

d3.json("http://localhost:8082/charts/dashboard/index", function (data) {
    data = dimple.filterData(data, "monthYear", [
                                                     "Jan-2015", "Feb-2015", "Mar-2015", "Apr-2015", "May-2015", "Jun-2015",
                                                     "Jul-2015", "Aug-2015", "Sep-2015", "Oct-2015", "Nov-2015", "Dec-2015"
                                                 ]);                                       

            //console.log(data);
//Create the indicator chart on the right of the main chart
var indicator = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
//Pick blue as the default and orange for the selected month
var defaultColor = indicator.defaultColors[0];
var indicatorColor = indicator.defaultColors[2];
//The frame duration for the animation in milliseconds
var frame = 2000;

var firstTick = true;
//Place the indicator bar chart to the right
indicator.setBounds(800, 49, 153, 311);
//Add dates along the y axis
var y = indicator.addCategoryAxis("y", "monthYear");
y.addOrderRule("Date", "Asc");

// Use sales for bar size and hide the axis
var x = indicator.addMeasureAxis("x", "energyConsumption");
x.hidden = true;
//Add the bars to the indicator and add event handlers
var s = indicator.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);
s.addEventHandler("click", onClick);
// Draw the side chart
indicator.draw();
//Remove the title from the y axis
y.titleShape.remove();

// Remove the lines from the y axis
y.shapes.selectAll("line,path").remove();

// Move the y axis text inside the plot area
y.shapes.selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "start")
        .style("font-size", "11px")
        .attr("transform", "translate(18, 0.5)");         

// Manually set the bar colors
s.shapes
        .attr("rx", 10)
        .attr("ry", 10)
        .style("fill", function (d) { return (d.y === 'Jan-2015' ? indicatorColor.fill : defaultColor.fill) })
        .style("stroke", function (d) { return (d.y === 'Jan-2015' ? indicatorColor.stroke : defaultColor.stroke) })
        .style("opacity", 0.4);

//draw the main chart
//this is the main chart for dual axis.

var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
chart.setBounds(60,20,680,330);

// Add your x axis - nothing unusual here
var x = chart.addMeasureAxis("x", "Date");
// First y axis is the combination axis for revenue and profit
var y1 = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Temperature");
// Second is the units only
var y2 = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Energy Consumption");

var bars = chart.addSeries("Energy Comsuption", dimple.plot.bar, [x,y2]);

var lines = chart.addSeries("Weather Report", dimple.plot.line, [x,y1]);

bars.barGap = 0.5;
// Colour the bars manually so they don't overwhelm the lines
chart.assignColor("Energy Comsuption", "black", "black", 0.15);
var story = chart.setStoryboard("monthYear", onTick);
//Change the frame duration
story.frameDuration = frame;
// Order the storyboard by date
story.addOrderRule("Date");
//x.dateParseFormat = "%m/%Y";
//x.addOrderRule("Date");    

// Here's how you add a legend for just one series.  Excluding the last parameter
// will include every series or an array of series can be passed to select more than
// one
//chart.addLegend(60, 5, 680, 10, "right", lines);

chart.draw();
//Orphan the legends as they are consistent but by default they
// will refresh on tick
chart.legends = [];
// Remove the storyboard label because the chart will indicate the
// current month instead of the label
story.storyLabel.remove();

// On click of the side chart
function onClick(e) {
    // Pause the animation
    story.pauseAnimation();
    // If it is already selected resume the animation
    // otherwise pause and move to the selected month
    if (e.yValue === story.getFrameValue()) {
        story.startAnimation();
    } else {
        story.goToFrame(e.yValue);
        story.pauseAnimation();
    }
}

// On tick of the main charts storyboard
function onTick(e) {
    if (!firstTick) {
        // Color all shapes the same
        s.shapes
                .transition()
                .duration(frame / 2)
                .style("fill", function (d) { return (d.y === e ? indicatorColor.fill : defaultColor.fill) })
                .style("stroke", function (d) { return (d.y === e ? indicatorColor.stroke : defaultColor.stroke) });
    }
    firstTick = false;
}
});
...................
```

My data is somewhat like this:-

```
    [{"country":"Australia","state":"New south wales","region":"Sydney",
"suburbs":"Canterbury-Bankstown","temperature":20.0,"humidity":25.0,"precipitation":11.0,"date":"Jan/01/2015",
"energyConsumption":0.141,"monthYear":"Jan-2015"},
{"country":"Australia","state":"New south wales","region":"Sydney","suburbs":"Canterbury-Bankstown",
"temperature":20.0,"humidity":25.0,"precipitation":11.0,"date":"Jan/02/2015",
"energyConsumption":0.088,"monthYear":"Jan-2015"},
{"country":"Australia","state":"New south wales","region":"Sydney","suburbs":"Canterbury-Bankstown",
"temperature":20.0,"humidity":25.0,"precipitation":11.0,"date":"Jan/03/2015",
"energyConsumption":0.078,"monthYear":"Jan-2015"},{"country":"Australia","state":"New south wales","region":"Sydney","suburbs":"Canterbury-Bankstown",
"temperature":20.0,"humidity":25.0,"precipitation":11.0,"date":"Jan/04/2015",
"energyConsumption":0.151,"monthYear":"Jan-2015"},{"country":"Australia","state":"New south wales","region":"Sydney",
"suburbs":"Canterbury-Bankstown","temperature":20.0,"humidity":25.0,"precipitation":11.0,"date":"Jan/05/2015",
"energyConsumption":0.146,"monthYear":"Jan-2015"},
{"country":"Australia","state":"New south wales","region":"Sydney",
"suburbs":"Canterbury-Bankstown","temperature":20.0,"humidity":25.0,"precipitation":11.0,"date":"Jan/06/2015",
"energyConsumption":0.077,"monthYear":"Jan-2015"},{"country":"Australia","state":"New south wales","region":"Sydney",
"suburbs":"Canterbury-Bankstown","temperature":20.0,"humidity":25.0,"precipitation":11.0,
"date":"Jan/07/2015","energyConsumption":0.052,"monthYear":"Jan-2015"},
{"country":"Australia","state":"New south wales","region":"Sydney","suburbs":"Canterbury-Bankstown","temperature":20.0,"humidity":25.0,
"precipitation":11.0,"date":"Jan/08/2015","energyConsumption":0.055,"monthYear":"Jan-2015"}
```

Comment: can you please share your code on jsbin or fiddle. It will be easier for us to work with it. Thank you! (Data can be dummy data, if you can't share part of it)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/94wtLjmm/

Answer (score 0):

[JSBIN Example](http://jsbin.com/qupevuhaqe/edit?html,output)

Please take a look at the dual y-axis I created with your data.

There is few things your doing wrong.

```
var x = chart.addMeasureAxis("x", "Date");
// First y axis is the combination axis for revenue and profit
var y1 = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Temperature");
// Second is the units only
var y2 = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Energy Consumption");

var bars = chart.addSeries("Energy Comsuption", dimple.plot.bar, [x,y2]);

var lines = chart.addSeries("Weather Report", dimple.plot.line, [x,y1]);
```

**Date**, **Temperature**, **Energy Consumption**, **Weather Report**. All of this is not valid, because that not how its define on your data. You have to give exact name as appears on your data.

I only create dual axis for you, I think you can add all the other details starting from there. If you have any other question feel free to post